# How to prevent Python script from Force exit?

Tags: python, linux, unix

I am running a python script and trying to prevent from force exiting or print an error message or log that into the log file.

I am already using `logging.info("")` for logging.. or just `print` for printing something..

but what or how do I create a method or function that can either do print or log when it force exit?

For example, if my test.py is running and I press <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to exit out.. I want to log that or print out..

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
logging.info("Checked for signal to stop")
if stop:
        logging.info("Inside of main if loop for stop signal")
        logging.info("Stop signal captured. Exiting the program")
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message + "Stop signal captured. Exiting the program")
        sys.exit("EXIT SIGNAL CAPTURED: EXITING")
```

I am using above coding for logging for when I want to exit the program.
But this doesn't deal with something like `ctrl + c` I want to also log just in case program exit by accident or something

Comment: Are you wanting to log other exits, or just when `ctrl + c` is used?

Comment: You want to read about python exception handling.  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: It would be more helpful if you told us why your code is "force exiting"

Comment: Take a look to `atexit` too https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Use try and except:

```
try:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
    logging.info("Checked for signal to stop")
    if stop:
        logging.info("Inside of main if loop for stop signal")
        logging.info("Stop signal captured. Exiting the program")
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message + "Stop signal captured.     Exiting the program")
        sys.exit("EXIT SIGNAL CAPTURED: EXITING")
except KeyboardInterrupt as kbe:
    log.info(str(kbe))
```

You could also leverage the `atexit` module to execute a function when the script exits.

```
import atexit

def alldone():
    log.warning('Something went wrong')

# your code here...
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

Answer (score 0):

You should likely take a look at [Python Signal Handlers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html) (specifically signal.CTRL_C_EVENT).

Here is a more-complete answer... NOTE: You can make your processes fairly unkillable by using such things.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import signal, os
import time

def handler( signum, frame ):
  print "Signal handler caught", signum, "@", time.ctime()
  if signum == 2:
    raise "Caught Signal 2 - Exiting"

#
# Windows Supported Values
#
#signal.signal( signal.SIGABRT, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIGFPE, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIGILL, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIGSEGV, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIGTERM, handler )

#
# UNIX Supported Values (YMMV)
#
signal.signal( signal.SIGABRT, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGALRM, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGBUS, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGCHLD, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGCLD, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGCONT, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGFPE, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGHUP, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGILL, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGINT, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGIO, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGIOT, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIGKILL, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGPIPE, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGPOLL, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGPROF, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGPWR, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGQUIT, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGRTMAX, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGRTMIN, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGSEGV, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIGSTOP, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGSYS, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGTERM, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGTRAP, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGTSTP, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGTTIN, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGTTOU, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGURG, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGUSR1, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGUSR2, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGVTALRM, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGWINCH, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGXCPU, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIGXFSZ, handler )
#signal.signal( signal.SIG_DFL, handler )
signal.signal( signal.SIG_IGN, handler )


print time.ctime(), " - Started"

while True:
  time.sleep( 1 )
  print " Tick:", time.ctime()
```

Comment: I edited the question. I was using something similar but does this catch all exiting? such as ctrl + c ?

Comment: You should try running the script and test to see what happens when you send different signals... it's just an indefinite loop that prints the time once a second - and calls the handler for pretty much any signal it receives. In the case of UN\*X, for example, a CTRL-C sends signal 2 (signal.SIGINT). In the case of your rephrased question, you likely just want to set SIGINT to be handled by a function like "stop" (which should be a def, not an if, which accepts two arguments).