# How to ignore keyboard input in Python while sleeping

Tags: python

While sleeping, I want all keyboard input to be ignored.

I tried this:

```
time.sleep(10)
while msvcrt.kbhit():
    flush = input()
input_code = input()
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: Could be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523657/how-to-prevent-python-script-from-force-exit

Comment: There is a good example on [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Keyboard_input/Flush_the_keyboard_buffer#Python) on how to flush the keyboard buffer. It uses the `msvcrt` module as well

Answer (score 0):

It should be `msvcrt.getch()` inside the loop, not `input()`:

```
time.sleep(10)
while msvcrt.kbhit():
    msvcrt.getch()
input_code = input()
```

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what happens?